# AngularJS - ng-show with ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a simple AngularJS app, that retrieves some data from openWeatherAPI and return some values.

Now I want to be able to display the air temperature in either celsius or fahrnheit. I figured I'd do this using `ng-show` and `ng-click`. Somehow I can't seem to get it to work.

What I do is define a variable called stopinje like this: `$scope.stopinje = true;`. Then I want to change this to false using ng-click, so when a user clicks a button, the celsius degrees will disappear, and the fahrnheit ones will appear.

My HTML:

```
<li ng-show="{{!stopinje}}">{{ fahrnheit }}</li>
<li ng-show="{{!stopinje}}"><button ng-click="stopinje = true">show temperature in celsius</button></li>
<li ng-show="{{stopinje}}">{{ celsius }}&nbsp;&deg;C</li>
<li ng-show="{{stopinje}}"><button ng-click="stopinje = false">show temperature in fahrnheit</button></li>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.stopinje = true;
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/NxOwOX?editors=1010) of the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-show` directive doesn't like the `{{ }}` syntax. Just provide it an expression directly:

```
<li ng-show="!stopinje">{{ fahrnheit }}</li>
```